# Mongoose - Self-referential deep populate error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate a self-referential model a few times recursively. Here's my schema:

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  counter: { type: Number },
  children: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'test' } ]
});
var models = {
  Test: mongoose.model('test', TestSchema)
};
```

So far, this functioning code populates everything one level:

```
models.Test.find().populate('children').exec(function(err, doc) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
  else {
    res.send(doc);
  }     });
```

But when I try to do something like:

```
models.Test.find().populate('children').populate('children.children').exec(function(err, doc) {
```

or even:

```
models.Test.find().populate('children').exec(function(err, doc) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
  else {
    models.Test.populate(doc, 'children.children', function(err, doc) {
       res.send(doc);
    });
  }
});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'path' of undefined
    at search (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2059:28)
    at search (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2078:22)
    at Function._getSchema (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2085:5)
    at populate (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1706:22)
    at Function.Model.populate (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1686:5)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (..../api/api.js:22:19)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (..../api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
```

The [mongoose 3.6 release notes](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#added-modelpopulatedocs-opts-cb) say that deep populates are allowed using Model.populate, but that's giving me an error. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

[The Mongoose docs for the Model.populate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) states that the second parameter should be an options object, and not a string.

Here's the example they provide:

```
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  var opts = [
      { path: 'company', match: { x: 1 }, select: 'name' }
    , { path: 'notes', options: { limit: 10 }, model: 'override' }
  ]

  User.populate(user, opts, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user);
  })
})
```

So yours should look something like:

```
models.Test.find().populate('children').exec(function(err, doc) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
  else {
    var opts = [
      { path: 'children.children' }
    ];
    models.Test.populate(doc, opts, function(err, doc) {
       res.send(doc);
    });
  }
});
```